# List bullet alignment changes when LI contains a block-level empty element

Tags: css

I hope someone can explain this odd CSS issue I'm encountering.

I have an empty element (think `<img>` or `<input>`) inside a `li`. When I change the display style on the empty element to "block", the alignment of the bullet on the `li` changes. If I do the same thing with a non-empty element (`<span>`, say), the bullet alignment does not change.

The bullet alignment changes even if the empty element is inside another block-level element (`<div>`).

Here are two examples on JSFiddle:

1. [Using an `<img>` element](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck7SC/2/)
2. [Using a `<span>` element](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck7SC/3/)

And screenshots of the results (`<img>` on the left, `<span>` on the right:

[image: Results: img on left; span on right]

I have two questions:

1. Why do the bullets do this?
2. How can I make the bullets in the `<img>` example line up the same way as in the `<span>` example?

For reference, the stylesheet:

```
ul { background: lightgreen; width: 100px; padding-left: 50px; }
div { background: lightblue; }
img { background: lightcoral; }
li { background: lightyellow; }

img { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
img[rel] { display: block; }
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><img rel></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><img></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><img rel></div>
    <p> ! </p>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><img></div>
    <p> ! </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(I know my `<img>` elements don't have `src` attributes. This is just for illustration purposes. BTW, it still works in Google Chrome, but not Firefox.)

Comment: seems the list dot lines up where the text is at on FF. Might be easier for you to line them up using a background image instead of the actual list style

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: @Huangism That might work, but I'd rather avoid background images for other reasons, and my question is just as much about my own curiosity as it is about finding a fix.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I wasn't clear about that, was I? I've edited the question with more info and hopefully made things clearer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this relates to an actual setup. Does it? Just curious

Comment: @ZachSaucier You mean real-life example? I was writing numbered instructions each with a small illustration (actually a figure with img + caption). Leaving the img inline or changing to inline-block leaves extra space below it (because vertical-align is baseline by default). My first attempt to fix was to change the img to block, and was surprised to find the number jump down to the next paragraph. Hence, this question.

Comment: I suppose I'm just surprised by the use of a list every time just for one bullet each. Not a problem, just curious

Comment: @ZachSaucier Oh that! No, that was just to make the results easier to see on JSFiddle. The original is just one OL.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but I noticed the same thing when the CSS rule "text-align:center;" acted on the li . An empty li caused the bullet to be displayed on the left side of the containing element, and an li with text caused the bullet to be displayed immediately to the left of the centered text. I investigated a bit using Developer's Tools. When I inspected an empty li, the bullet was outside of the shaded area. When I inspected the li with text, the bullet was inside the shaded area. That might make one think that the bullet became part of InnerHTML and/or the #text element, but inspectin

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with alignment for images, they default to the bottom alignment which causes the list items to move with them. In order to fix this problem, add this to the image tag:

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The `display: inline-block` is the only display type that will allow vertical align to work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Mac and it comes out exactly as the content with the span example. Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/abO1SUT

Comment: No, vertical-align is not the issue here. I already know how to use inline-block, etc. The question is why do BLOCK-level elements behave differently depending on whether they are empty (img, input) or not. See my img example: The bullet aligns with the first content-containing element (the following p element or the space character in the div) and ignores the empty element.

Comment: See also this example using input (which is by default inline-block): http://jsfiddle.net/Ck7SC/4/